# tf_agents.agent.collect_poilcy not obeying action_spec of the environment

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning

I am experimenting with `tf_agents` and trying to train an agent in a custom environment. I noticed have setup an agent using

```py
tf_agent = PPOAgent(
    tf_env.time_step_spec(),
    tf_env.action_spec(),
    actor_net=actor_net,
    value_net=value_net,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    train_step_counter=train_step_counter
)
tf_agent.initialize()
```

and I the environment is a `TFPYEnvironment`-wrapped `PyEnvironment` with

```py
tf_env.action_spec()
>> BoundedTensorSpec(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.float32, name='boost', minimum=array(-1.e-04, dtype=float32), maximum=array(1.e-04, dtype=float32))
```

Not the trying agent's `.policy.action` works as intended:

```py
initial_time_step = tf_env.reset()
tf_agent.policy.action(initial_time_step) 
>> PolicyStep(action=<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1.1164140e-05, 1.7829814e-05, 2.5916113e-05]], dtype=float32)>, state=(), info=())
```

i. e. the returned value are inside the specified bounds.

But the agent's `.collect_poilcy.action` does not obey these bounds:

```py
initial_time_step = tf_env.reset()
tf_agent.collect_policy.action(initial_time_step) 
>> PolicyStep(action=<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[-0.17758366,  0.14912587, -0.0418932 ]], dtype=float32)>, state=(), info={'dist_params': {'loc': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1.1164140e-05, 1.7829814e-05, 2.5916113e-05]], dtype=float32)>, 'scale': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.35000002, 0.35000002, 0.35000002]], dtype=float32)>}})
```

I know that the `collect_policy` behaves a little different to "explore" the environment - but is that really intended? It leads to enormous changes in the state of the environment and makes training impossible because NaNs occur really fast.

My current workaround is, to wrap the environment into an `ActionClipWrapper` before the `TFPyEnvironment`-wrapper, like

```py
env = ActionClipWrapper(env)
tf_env = TFPyEnvironment(env)
```

this does prevent the NaNs but I am not sure if the agent is able to learn anything like this.

Edit: Note that the environment is also already wrapped into the ActionClipWrapper with the `.policy.action` and `.collect_poilcy.action` above.